# javascript error in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I need help with an error message I am getting in IE6+.
Note though that the code is working fine.

*Message: Object expected 

Line: 38 

Char: 4 

Code: 0 

URI: http://localhost/dropbox/panorama/index.php?lang=gr*

What is actually at line 38 is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        slideShow();
    });
</script>
```

**LINE 38 is the one where I am calling my "slideShow()" function**  
Note also that these function is stored in an external file.

These are the contents of the external file:

```
$(function slideShow() {
    //Set the opacity of all images to 0
    $('#gallery li').css({opacity: 0.0});

    //Get the first image and display it (set it to full opacity)
    $('#gallery li:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

    //Call the gallery imgGallery to run the slideshow, 5000: 5 seconds interval
    setInterval('imgGallery()',4000);   
});

$(function imgGallery() {
    //Get the first image
    var current = ($('#gallery li.show')?  $('#gallery li.show') : $('#gallery li:first'));

    //Get next image, if reached last image, start over from the first image
    var next = ((current.next().length) ? (current.next()) : $('#gallery li:first'));


    //Set the fade in effect for the next image
    next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('show')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

    //Hide current image
    current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000)
        .removeClass('show');
});
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: Have you refereced the jQuery library?

Comment: yes sure I did. I also imported the external js file

Comment: ok, Had to ask! what is in your slideShow(); method?

Comment: I included the contents of the external js file in my question. Thanks

Comment: epascarello's answer looks correct, id give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

try and replace `setInterval('imgGallery()',4000);` with `setInterval(imgGallery,4000);`
If that does not work, this should:
`setInterval(function(){imgGallery();},4000)`

Answer (score 1):

You wrapped the functions slideshow and imgGallery inside of a jQuery object.

```
$(function slideShow(){

}

$(function imgGallery() { 
  ...
});
```

That means that they will not be in global scope. Remove the $() since it is not required.

Comment: epascarello, I did what you suggested but I did not work. However, when I put the two functions in the same file where I am calling them, it DID work. So, now, I want to put these two functions in a separate file and then import it? How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Um, are you sure the file is being loaded?

Comment: I just put a simple alert command at the external file, and it did not execute. Hmmm, that means the file is not loaded ha? I guess you are right.  The path to the js file is correct though!  I dont know

Answer (score 0):

The way IE references line numbers isn't always 100% depending how/if the file is included. Regardless comment all the code out of the slide show function, and see if it still throws the error, if it does the line number is actually pointing to something else.

If it doesn't, bring each line back 1 at a time until the error occurs.

Sadly this is the best way I know of debugging in ie6

Answer (score 0):

A quote from Paul Irish: "setInterval is a JERK!!" from Paul Irish : 10 Things I Learned from the jQuery Source. http://vimeo.com/12529436

Fast forward to 07:40 and lasts about 5mins. Intead of using setInterval you can use setTimeout and call itself.